# How to setup Thanos backup historical data on Prometheus local disk

Tags: prometheus, monitor, prometheus-operator, thanos

I'm doing a POC to integrate Thanos to our Prometheus cluster using Prometheus-operator. The system works well and uploads local files every two hours to S3. However, looks like the sidecar not backup our historical data at Prometheus local disk. After I reduce retention those data got lost. I'm not sure if I should the historical data backup can be enabled by some settings or sidecar can only backup data generated on the fly? If that's the case how we can back up our historical data to S3? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Historical data migration was only introduced in v0.3.0 and current version support by Prometheus-Operator is v0.2.1. Thanos team plan to add v0.3.2 to operator as they fixed last pending issue on store gateway after v0.3.1.